# Dynamically loading Java class vs implementing LUA

Tags: java, lua

A friend and I are writing a game in Java which contains a lot of items. Each item has certain static attributes that we will be storing in a database. However, items also have a special ability with a special effect. Often these effects would be quite unique and as such it makes sense that they are implemented in the definition of the item.

As the items are stored in a database we've been trying to decide how to load these special effects. What would be ideal is to have a item definition similar to the one below:

**Name** Dog
**Size** 5
**Description** Deals damage to surrounding players if player is below 50% health
**Effect** `if(currentplayer.health < 50) { entities.groups.surrounding.reduceHealth(20);}`

We've been discussing two different solutions. The first is to somehow compile and store java code in the database and the other is to implement LUA. Unfortunately neither of us have experience with LUA and are unsure if this is the way to go. On the other hand, the precompiled java solution seems a bit 'hacky'. In addition to that we can foresee issues with large chains of member calls, e.g. `a.player.head.hat.size.width.increase(1)`

What I would like to know:

- How would these methods compare with large numbers of entity definitions (5000 +)?
- Is there are clear path to take here or is there another superior solution?
- Would it be bad practice to use Java  as a scripting language as well as for the game engine?

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered creating paramaterized decorators (or some other approach) and simply storing the parameters in the database rather than the functionality? It would make things a bit grosser in terms of database layout, but it would allow you to avoid having to store source code or implement a scripting language.

For example, you could essentially have each `item` entity have a one to many relationship with `special_ability` through special ability instances. Furthermore, each of these `special_ability_assignments` would have have a one to many relationship with parameters.

This means that you could give your `Steel Sword of Rage` a special ability of `Rage` with parameters `25` and `200`. Your `Rage` decorator would then modify the weapon's effect to increase attack by 200 when the player's health is below 25%.

Likewise, your `Mithril Sword of Rage and Bleed` could have a `Rage` special ability with 30/250 (+250 PAtk when health <= 30%) and `Bleed` special ability with 20/10/50 where each strike has a 20% chance to cause bleeding which will cause 10 damage per second, decaying at 50% per bleed.

This would of course make your database grow in complexity (though I feel it fits the complexity of what you're trying to do) and you would have to abuse reflection (well, you wouldn't have to -- it would just be the easiest way to do it [and likely easiest to maintain]). Luckily though, you could just load items once when your game starts up, and you would only have to worry about the performance issues/type checking issues once.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say based on what you post what is better, although with th3 Lua path you can just run the stored code whereas with java path you will have to compile the java at load time.

If you search for "embed Lua in java" you will find several different java libraries that make Lua easy to use from java, like luaj, Lua java, khalua, mochalua etc. Which one to use will depend on the specifics of what you want to do so you'll have to try a few of them out.

Lua is easy language to learn.